# assigning retrieved data using ajax to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

im new to javascript and ajax, i am trying to figure out how to assign to a global variable the retrieved data using ajax. my code looks like this:

```
  $('#store').live('pagecreate',function(event){

         var address;

                  $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "testing.php",
                  data: ({task: 'store'}),
                  cache: false,
                  dataType: "text",
                  success: onSuccess
                });

        function onSuccess(data)
       {
            address = data;
       }

               alert (address);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider:

- If you want `address` to be global variable, don't define it inside the block. It won't be visible outside the block you define it in, so it's not a global variable. Define it e.g. at the very beginning of your script, outside of any blocks.
- The `alert (address);` doesn't make sense there, since it most likely gets called before the `onSuccess` function is called. Put it inside the `onSuccess` function if you want to see the value of `address` after the data has been assigned.